# When is innodb_lock_wait_timeout ignored?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, deadlock

I'm having a weird case of the classic deadlock exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.

The code is identified and indeed, it's possible to get a deadlock. The thing is that I'm getting the exception immediately. I've set the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable to 1 hour (3600). But still, the exception comes right away.

What exactly is happening?

Comment: Maybe MySQL's gotten smart enough to recognize circular deadlocks and not have to wait for the timeout to hit.

Comment: Let's hope not. :-) Is it possible to override the timeout at runtime ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting a deadlock the lock_wait_timeout variable is how long a query will wait to acquire locks before timing out - not the same thing.

From the manual:
The timeout in seconds an InnoDB transaction may wait for a row lock before giving up. The default value is 50 seconds. A transaction that tries to access a row that is locked by another InnoDB transaction will hang for at most this many seconds before issuing the following error:

You'd see this if you were hitting the timeout.  You have a proper deadlock that needs fixing.
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: is there any way to check effective value of lock_wait_timeout??

Comment: To see the current values, run `show global variables like '%wait_timeout';`

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

> The lock wait timeout value does not apply to deadlocks when innodb_deadlock_detect is enabled (the default)